# Creating a Local WordPress Site Using XAMPP or Wamp ..but getting this error..Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Try Again

.
How to resolve this Error.. ?
I've tried Wordpress installation on both Xampp and Wamp servers...
getting the same error every time..on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says everything you have to know. Wordpress can not contact MySQL. Look in your wp-config.php if the MySQL-crendentials are correct. Find more information at https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/.

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner , appreciate your help ..thanks